# Open Derby/JDBC database in file system

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, derby

I have a database that is used in Java with Derby/JDBC. In the file system, I can see the following entries:

- log (folder)
- - log.ctrl (file)
- - log142.dat (file)
- - logmirror.ctrl (file)
- seg0 (folder)
- - c... (60 files with 8-7000 kB)
- tmp (folder)
- db.lck (file)
- service.properties (file)

Is there any chance to open this database? I would like to convert this database to SQLite so I need to see the structure at least.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Why not just dump it out using some quick java and a Derby JDBC driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should install Derby if have not already. Derby comes with a command line tool `ij`. Use this tool to dump the tables as sql queries or csv files. You can uses these to import to sqlite.

[First choose the output format using](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/ctoolsimportdefaultformat.html)

[And then use these SQLs](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/rtoolsimport91458.html) on the command line of IJ to export to file.

[Find details about ij here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/getstart/) after clicking this link...click Running IJ.

[Some basic IJ tool example](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/tools/rtoolsijcomrefshow.html)

[For exporting data out of Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/tools/ctoolsimport16245.html)

**Snippet for running IJ**

`Method When to Use Command
Run ij as a standalone command. Use this method if you are relatively new to the Java programming language and new to Derby.    Follow the steps in Setting the environment variables before you run the ij tool using this method. To run the ij script from the command line, use:
ij
You must add the DERBY_HOME/bin directory to your PATH environment variable before you can run the ij tool.

The ij script sets the appropriate environment variables, including the CLASSPATH, and starts the ij tool.`

**Example of tool CLI:**

ij> connect 'sample' as sample1;

ij> connect 'newDB;create=true' as newDB;

ij(NEWDB)> show connections;

SAMPLE1 -        jdbc:derby:sample

NEWDB* -        jdbc:derby:newDB;create=true

- = current connection

ij(NEWDB)>

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you tell me how to use the ij tool please? Do you use it from code? In Eclipse, I've added the Derby plugin and I'm able to connect to my database now. I can select rows from single tables but derby doesn't seem to have something like "SHOW TABLES" ...

Comment: Derby has `SHOW TABLES` http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/tools/rtoolsijcomrefshow.html And this link also has example on how to connect to DB using `ij`

Comment: Yes, but how can I execute Derby commands such as "ij> show tables" when I'm working with Java? So far, I only have an instance of java.sql.Connection.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at [SQuirrel SQL](http://www.squirrelsql.org/) as it can copy data from one database to another.  Look on the [plugins](http://www.squirrelsql.org/index.php?page=plugins) page for the DBCopy plugin.  With SQuirreL you can also right-click on a table in the objects view and generate the CREATE TABLE statement for the structure, etc.
Handy.